# Is Mission Control behavior exposed or how would I hack it?

Tags: macos

I haven't written a Mac app in 10 years and will get the terms wrong.

I want to change the default names for Mission Control desktops: Desktop 1, Desktop n, etc. Is there any API that would allow me to intercept or override this naming. Failing that, where would I begin to research how to patch this behavior? Does anyone know of any tutorials for patching Mac system behaviors? Who else tries to do something like this?

Comment: Looks like "code injection" is the search term I needed to use to begin researching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Code injection" is where I need to begin researching.